# Career prospects as development economist

Tags: development-economics

I'm studying economics and I'm finding myself more and more wanting to specialize in development economics. However, I'm feeling uncertain about the job prospects in this regard. Are there any career prospects for development economists outside of academia or development banks?

Comment: I think the World Bank has a premier development economics practice. In general, I think you'll be looking at public sector jobs (i.e., government).